# Open itunes from a link

Tags: html

How can I write a link in html to open itunes in Mac?
What actually I want to do is when someone clicks on a link in my website , it  should open itunes?

Answer (score 6):

Here is such a link:

```
<a href="itms://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=307538288">Tap 'n' Pop Classic</a>
```

This will work only if the website visitor has iTunes installed on his machine.

Answer (score 1):

Apple offers the [iTunes Link Maker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/), which let's you generate such links.

Comment: This actually generates a HTTP Link, the iTunes website will then redirect iOS clients to an URL with the iTunes URL Schema (itunes://)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [iTunes Link Maker](http://iTunesLinkMaker.com) and **remove the country code** (i.e. "**us**") out of the link and it would always work open iTunes always and not a browser on the way (if there is iTunes installed on the target system).

You can also **remove the app_name** you don't really need it (if your app name would be changed nothing happen, actually the name is ignored).